# Juju MySQL for WordPress with Percona

Tags: mysql, juju, wordpress

Is there any benefit in using Percona as a distro for WordPress? Does it actually allow me to use Extradb or is it still limited to Innobd?

Answer (score 1):

The two will work together just fine, not sure if WordPress makes use of ExtraDB or not, it's something the WordPress charm actively checks for. I would ask the WordPress people about support for ExtraDB and WordPress.